# how to return positive values of original array into a new array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm supposed to declare a 15 integer array and return a second array containing the positive integers of the original array. I'm having trouble returning the second array from the method.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class array4
    {
      public static void main(String [] args)
      {
        int [] num = new int[15]; int [] positives = new int [15];
        getInput(num);
        positives = getPositives(num);
        printResults(num, positives);
      }
      public static void getInput(int [] num){
        int x;
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 15 integers");
        for(x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    num[x] = kbd.nextInt();

   }
  public static int getPositives(int [] num){
    int position = 0;  
    int [] positive = new int [15];
    for(int i =0; i < num.length; i++){  

      if(num[i] >=0) {
        positive[position] = num[i];  
        position++;  }}
    return positive;
  }


  public static void printResults(int [] num, int [] positives){
    System.out.println("You entered"); int x;
    for(x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
    System.out.println(num[x]);
    System.out.println("Your positive integers are ");
    for(x = 0; x < positives.length; x++)
    System.out.println(positives[x]);}}
```

Comment: For starters, you're calling getPositives() when you have declared getPositive()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `public static int[] getPositive()`. The return type is an array of integers, but you declared it as `int`.

Comment: Is there an easier way to declare the dimensions of the second array so that when I print it, it doesn't gives zeroes for the unused slots?

Comment: You can `return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(positive,position)`, which gives a copy of the array with the elements from 0 to `position-1`.

Answer (score 1):

In `getPositive` you are returning an `int` rather than an `int[]`

I think your approach is flawed though.

If you create an `ArrayList` and put the positive numbers in there, then turn that list into an Array, you won't have any empty places in your array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare getPositive to return an array:

```
public static int[] getPositive(int [] num){
```

Also, you don't need to initialize `positive` in the `main()` method.  That just allocates an array the will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must return integer array and not a single integer value. Here is modified piece of code :

```
 public static int[] getPositive(int [] num){
int position = 0;  
int [] positive = new int [15];
for(int i =0; i < num.length; i++){  

  if(num[i] >=0) {
    positive[position] = num[i];  
    position++;  }}
return positive; // Wont give compilation error now
```

}